# Codeigniter project on live server page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter project which works fine on Localhost. Now i upload it on live server.But it gives me 404 Page Not Found error. i have uploaded it into
www.mydomain.com/city/ folder .So far i configured database name,password in application/config/database.php and change the base_url to www.mydomain.com/city/ in application/config/config.php

my .htaccess looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anybody help please?

Comment: what is your domain??

Comment: sorry. it will be like www.mydomain.com/city/

Comment: try www.mydomain.com/index.php/city/ working or not ?

Comment: no bro.not found appears

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using?'

Comment: codeigniter version 3.0.3  and localhost PHP Version 5.6.8 and live server PHP Version 5.3.29

Comment: do you have your controller, model names start with a capital letter? for e.g if you have "home.php" you need to have "Home.php"

Comment: yes all controller and models are capital letter as well class name.do i need to all view pages to be capital letter?? . In routes.php default controller index be capital letter???

Comment: Is `city` directory where whole CI application took place? In other words is your CI installation in subdirectory of root on live server?

Comment: yes.My CI project is inn city directory .

Answer (score 0):

may be file permission issue. take login to your cpanel of server and see the error log for 404 number error

Answer (score 0):

As Dray said in the comment section, your Controller names have to be capital letter in the url aswell as in the code (classname) and Filename.

See: [Codeigniter Class and filename case sensitive on Linux (centos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145215/codeigniter-class-and-filename-case-sensitive-on-linux-centos/31150718#31150718)

I assume you developed on a Windows machine (where it worked flawlessly despite the faulty case) and migrated you project to a Linux live server. I also fell for it when I moved to a Linux server.

Comment: Is i have to call the controller from menu or other place(with capitalize controller name) like controller/function  to Controller/function if i use capital letter of a controller file name

Comment: No, it is not obligated. You can use strtolower route values as well.