# codeigniterUnable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

i am using HVMC concept in codeigniter for my website .

it is working fine in my local system .

when i try to host it on my production server it is giving issue.

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.
```

you can find the issue in below url:http://matchinchrist.org/new/home/cms

Comment: Please add your `routes.php` (you can find it under application/config) file here.

Comment: Make sure your file names and class names are proper case sensitive.

Comment: routes.php file is already there

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36505693/3355243

Answer (score 0):

Do you work on Windows ?

File names are case sensitives on linux, but not on Windows...

Is the name of you controller exactly the same on your local machine and on your host ?

Comment: my local machine is window and hosting server is linux

Comment: Be sure that your filename and controller name respect the naming convention of Codeigniter

(Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145215/codeigniter-class-and-filename-case-sensitive-on-linux-centos)

Comment: i am using HMVC conpect