# Codeigniter 3.0.4 with 404 Page Not Found Error on my server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting

I am new to the codeigniter. After developing a web app on my localhost .So i uploaded my site on server and then i imported my database. after that i have changed the settings of database in database.php file .. and also i changed the base url in config.php file.

I am getting a **404 Page Not Found.
The page you requested was not found**. I dont know what is going wrong ..i have searched a lot but nothing helps. and my .htaccess file is empty ..means there is not a single line in it. and one more thing is that i purchase this from **godaddy** hosting may be  helpfull.

my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = '';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

my controller doctorscont.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Doctorscont extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() { 
         here is my code.....  */
   }
}
```

and my config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

[1]:

Comment: What's the version of your CI?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define doctorscont's route in routes.php.

Please add this line at the end of routes.php then visit

```
$route['doctorscont'] = 'Doctorscont';
```

If you still get 404 error, please try If it opens, you may want to remove index.php on URL. For this task, visit CodeIgniter [URLs Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

Edit:

Create a .htaccess file under your root (same folder with system and application) with the content below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Than open config.php and edit this line:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now you can get what you want.

Comment: Are you sure? Visit http://doctorsplace.co/index.php/doctorscont and see the new error :)

Comment: ya error is "No input file specified."  but what about home page http://doctorsplace.co/

Comment: First make the Doctorscont controller work, than we can check other thing.

Comment: Which libraries did you load in autoload.php? Is session library there? If you have, please add encryption key to config.php

This is not about your problem, I'm just giving a general info.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3+ the filenames must contain the first letter of each file as upper case. It will work in lowercase in your localhost environment but not on server.

Rename the file to '**D**octorscont.php' <strike>and you can use the class names as lowercase</strike>.

```
class Doctorscont extends CI_Controller
```

**Edit**: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: In CI3 versions you should have both class and file names with only the first letter upper case.

Comment: Not true, at least not necessary. The class names don't need to have the first letter upper case.

Comment: It's what the user guide says to do CI3 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: You're right. But I have several projects with lower case without any problem. But I do know that if I don't put the file names in upper case it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not made some changes at apache2 config level please do below changes.

1)sudo a2enmod rewrite

2)gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

3)add below to end of your conf file

```html
<Directory /var/www/html/>
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

4) Restart apache2 service by below command.
service apache2 restart

Best of luck.